# I can't get data from model

Tags: java, android, dao, pojo

I created a POJO model and did not call it out.

This is the code to run it.

```
DataObjectSelectGarage selectGarage = ...;
TextView.setText(selectGarage.getGaragename());
```

Do not know if it can run this way?

this is model

```
public class DataObjectSelectGarage implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("Garage_id")
    private int id;

    public int getGarage_id() {
     return id;
    }

    public void setgetGarage_id(String getGarage_id) {
     this.id = id;
    }

    @SerializedName("Garagename")
    private String name;

    public String getGaragename() {
     return name;
    }

    public void setGaragename(String name) {
     this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you initalize it on your oncreate? selectGarage = new DataObjectSelectGarage();

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setgetGarage_id(String getGarage_id) {
     this.id = id;
    }
```

The above set method assigning Id = id instead of id= getGarage_id

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work this way

```
DataObjectSelectGarage selectGarage;

TextView.setText(selectGarage.getGaragename());
```

As DataObjectSelectGarage is not initialized. You need to initialize it first.

Secondly in code you posted there are multiple logical bugs like you are passing UserId to HTTP request param without assigning value to it. Secondly without pasring response trying to present it to user.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
/*DataObjectSelectGarage dataObjectSelectGarage = new 
DataObjectSelectGarage();
String test1 = dataObjectSelectGarage.getGaragename();*/
tvTest.setText(selectGarage.getGaragename());
Log.d("Selectgarage",response.toString());
}
```

you need to parse the response string and then after initializing model object and setting values in it use it to show data on view.